# maven err - points at wrong local POM

Tags: java, maven, compiler-errors

i am getting the below error.. can anyone please help.

```
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.timwe.unity.core:unity-core-subscription-manager-crm-web:1.0.14-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.timwe.unity.core:unity-core-subscription-manager-crm:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 4, column 11
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.timwe.unity.core:unity-core-subscription-manager-crm-web:1.0.14-SNAPSHOT (D:\emomi\workspace\smSubscription\webapp-unity-celcom-subscription\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for com.timwe.unity.core:unity-core-subscription-manager-crm-web:1.0.14-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.timwe.unity.core:unity-core-subscription-manager-crm:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 4, column 11 -> [Help 2]
```

i get this when i do maven clean.

pom section with err:

```
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <parent>
    <groupId>com.timwe.unity.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>unity-core-subscription-manager-crm</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../</relativePath>
  </parent>
```

Comment: relative path is wrong... how is your project structure?

Answer (score 0):

settings.sml was missing in C:\Users\Developer.m2

working fine after adding the same